# How to send email in office 365 using office script excel online

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office365, excel-online

I'm currently creating an office script to send email from excel online(hosted in onedriveforbusiness). The components of the email am extracting from excel cell values. Have done a research and it looks to me that `office script` has syntax similar to javascript or typescript. I'm also not sure if the language used is `javascript or typescript`, kindly clarify for me on that.

In summary

1. I need a code sample on how to send email from office script in excel online(office 365)
2. I need to know what language is being used in office script, is it javascript or typescript.

Below is the  sample code office script have written and its failing when i run it.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Your code here

  // select a sheet
  let selected_sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()

  // get subject
  let subject = selected_sheet.getRange("C2")
  let subject_ = subject.getValue()

  // get body
  let body = selected_sheet.getRange("E2")
  let body_ = body.getValue()

  // to email
  let receivembx = selected_sheet.getRange("B2")
  let receivembx_ = receivembx.getValue()

  // from email
  let sendmbx = "emailhere"
  let pwd_ = "passwordhere"

  Email.send({
    Host: "smtp.office365.com",
    Username: sendmbx,
    Password: pwd_,
    To: receivembx_,
    From: sendmbx,
    Subject: subject_,
    Body: body_,

  }).then(
    console.log("mail sent successfully")
  );

  console.log(sendmbx)
}
```

Upon running that code, i get
[image]
[image]

Below is the snip for the excel online and office script.
[image]

Comment: Maybe try [Power Automate](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Send-an-email-to-the-email-address-found-in-excel-using-power/td-p/731230)?

Comment: Is there a way to implement a email sending snippet within the script? I believe if the language being used is `javascript or typescript` i can send an email

Comment: Looks to be typescript https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/tutorials/excel-tutorial

Comment: VBA is not supported in excel online

Comment: I just need a sample snippet on how to send the email from office script, from there i will able to customize my code based on excel values. Have not found any way to do this from internet. I'm new to office scripts that is why i had to seek for guidance.

Comment: There is no Email object in Office Scripts. So you can't pass in data to an Email object or use methods that send an email. I would recommend looking into using PowerAutomate for this. You can see an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/email-customization

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/876163/how-to-send-email-in-office-365-using-office-scrip

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1

The code editor you're using has more limited capabilities so you aren't permitted to directly send emails. With VBA this is somewhat intuitive as VBA has the power to do a lot with your PC (perhaps too much). You would be better off to try to use powerapps.

Since you asked for an example, [consider this one from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/email-images-chart-table).

Note that you can capture fields from an table in excel so that's how you would get a dynamic email address per message, etc.

### Question 2

You are using TypeScript, but very similar. The difference [is described as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/code-editor-environment#scripting-language-typescript-or-javascript):

"*Office Scripts are written in TypeScript, which is a superset of JavaScript. The Action Recorder generates code in TypeScript and the Office Scripts documentation uses TypeScript. Since TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, any scripting code that you write in JavaScript will work just fine.*"

Comment: Kindly note this is excel online

Comment: @Bernietechy So specify that it is Excel Online in the question - an important bit of info that you failed to include.

Comment: @Bernietechy, yes I know it's Excel online... I mentioned VBA only to indicate you should not confuse the fact that the task you're doing online is easy to do with the excel application vs using the web version. And as you requested a snipit or example of using excel and a mail program was included.